# Conformal holomorphic mapping from disc to square

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f$ be a holomorphic map from the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ to an open square $\mathbb{S}$ with its center at the origin. Given
$$ f(0) = 0, \qquad f'(z) \neq 0 \quad (z \in \mathbb{D}) $$
prove that
$$ if(z) = f(iz) \quad (z \in \mathbb{D}) $$

I see that $f^{-1}(if(z))$ is an automorphism of the disc and hence a rotation, but why does it have to be a rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: Presumably $f$ is supposed to be a bijection?

Comment: @arney, if you consider only the absolute values, then what you have is true. However in the current state you need bijectivity.

Comment: @Hmm. Sadly, the author of the problem book is not very rigorous. The original formulation admits the interpretation that $f$ is onto, but does not say anything about injectivity.

Comment: @amey, then you cannot use $f^{-1}$ at all, right?

Comment: @Hmm. Talking in terms of the inverse mapping theorem in neighbourhoods of zero

Comment: Yes, but then it will no longer be an automorphism since it will not be $1-1$. I think I have a solution, let me see...

Comment: @Hmm. Okay, some define conformal as locally biholomorphic, others as biholomorphic, and I could have learned about that on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biholomorphism#Alternative_definitions).

Comment: @arney, Yes you need biholomorphicity here. Otherwise I believe there are counterexamples, which sadly are not elementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have observed that $g(z)=f^{-1}(if(z))$ is a rotation, since it is an automorphism of the disk that fixes $0$.  To find out what it is a rotation by, you can just compute the derivative at $0$ by the chain rule: $$g'(0)=i(f^{-1})'(0)f'(0)=i$$
since $(f^{-1})'(z)=1/f'(f^{-1}(z)).$